# Is there a function to solve a rolling cumulative sum?

Tags: r

I have a DT with basically four columns. StockID, Month, Year and Return. I am trying to cumsum the last m-12 until m-2 returns for month m. So that for each month i get a column with the sum of the last 10 returns excluding the prior month.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am relatively new to r and hope somebody with more experience can help :)

```r
 Id RET.USD month year
 1: 13082U  -30.15     1 2001
 2: 13082U   29.46     2 2001
 3: 13082U   -9.23     3 2001
 4: 13082U  -30.68     4 2001
 5: 13082U   15.96     5 2001
 6: 13082U   -3.64     6 2001
 7: 13082U  -39.86     7 2001
 8: 13082U   13.55     8 2001
 9: 13082U    0.26     9 2001
10: 13082U   -1.10    10 2001
11: 13082U   19.28    11 2001
12: 13082U   -0.56    12 2001
13: 13082U   -3.31     1 2002
14: 13082U    0.48     2 2002
15: 13082U    0.86     3 2002
```

Comment: I think a combination of `zoo::rollapply` and `cumsum` might work. It would be immensely helpful if you provided usable representative data: please post the output from `dput(x)` where `x` has just enough relevant columns, and at least 15 rows (I'd think, due to `m-12` to `m-2`) or so. Knowing your expected values for at least one of those columns is important, too. Thanks!

Comment: `RcppRoll::roll_sum()` might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rollapply` with a width of `list(-seq(2, 12))` which means use offsets -2, -3, ..., -12 and the third argument says to sum the points at those offsets.  `partial = TRUE` means if those offsets don't exist since we are too close to the start of the series then just use whatever is available.  `fill = NA` says if there are no points at all at those offsets since we are too close to the start fill them in with NA.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, roll := rollapply(RET.USD, list(-seq(2, 12)), sum, partial = TRUE, fill = NA), by = Id]
```

giving:

```
 > DT
        Id RET.USD month year   roll
 1: 13082U  -30.15     1 2001     NA
 2: 13082U   29.46     2 2001     NA
 3: 13082U   -9.23     3 2001 -30.15
 4: 13082U  -30.68     4 2001  -0.69
 5: 13082U   15.96     5 2001  -9.92
 6: 13082U   -3.64     6 2001 -40.60
 7: 13082U  -39.86     7 2001 -24.64
 8: 13082U   13.55     8 2001 -28.28
 9: 13082U    0.26     9 2001 -68.14
10: 13082U   -1.10    10 2001 -54.59
11: 13082U   19.28    11 2001 -54.33
12: 13082U   -0.56    12 2001 -55.43
13: 13082U   -3.31     1 2002 -36.15
14: 13082U    0.48     2 2002  -6.56
15: 13082U    0.86     3 2002 -39.33
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(Id = c("13082U", "13082U", "13082U", "13082U", 
"13082U", "13082U", "13082U", "13082U", "13082U", "13082U", "13082U", 
"13082U", "13082U", "13082U", "13082U"), RET.USD = c(-30.15, 
29.46, -9.23, -30.68, 15.96, -3.64, -39.86, 13.55, 0.26, -1.1, 
19.28, -0.56, -3.31, 0.48, 0.86), month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L), year = c(2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But i think we need some adjustments. The output should have NAs until month 12. As it looks at past performance and sums the past 12 returns excl the last one. Thus, in line 12 should be the first sum with -55,43. Sorry when the way my question is asked, is not clear!

Comment: Omit partial= if you don't want partial sums.

Comment: Works perfectly ! So nice getting your help!

Comment: What if i have different Stock IDs? How can i change the code so it recognises if the stock changes?